# xslt distinct-values is not working for attributes

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml file, I need to find out the distinct attribute languages count present in multiple group.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <tns:DfCustomer>
<tns:Date_TimeList>
    <tns:Date_Time index="1">1404211736</tns:Date_Time>
</tns:Date_TimeList>
<tns:Short_NameList>
    <tns:Short_Name language="GB">ABC EUROPE</tns:Short_Name>
</tns:Short_NameList>
<tns:Name_1List>
    <tns:Name_1 language="GB">ABC EUROPE</tns:Name_1>
</tns:Name_1List>
<tns:Name_2List>
    <tns:Name_2 language="GB">ABC EUROPE</tns:Name_2>
</tns:Name_2List>
<tns:StreetList>
    <tns:Street language="GB">FRANKFURTER STR.107</tns:Street>
    <tns:Street language="FR">D-64807 DIEBURG</tns:Street>
</tns:StreetList>
<tns:address1List>
    <tns:address1 language="GB" index="1">Test GB Address 1</tns:address1>
    <tns:address1 language="FR" index="1">Test FR Address 1</tns:address1>
    <tns:address1 language="DE" index="1">Test DE Address 1</tns:address1>
    <tns:address1 language="GB" index="2">Test GB Address 2</tns:address1>
    <tns:address1 language="FR" index="2">Test FR Address 2</tns:address1>
    <tns:address1 language="GB" index="3">Test GB Address 3</tns:address1>
</tns:address1List>
<tns:Town_CountryList>
    <tns:Town_Country language="GB">GERMANY</tns:Town_Country>
</tns:Town_CountryList>
```

In the above example, I have 3 distinct languages like GB, DE and FR. I wish to get count 3. I tried following xslt/xpath function but nothing seems to work. It gives stack overflow error when iterating in for-each loop

1

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(dfns:*/dfns:*[@language]/@language))" />
```

2

```
<xsl:variable name="total">
    <xsl:for-each select="dfns:*/dfns:*[@language]/@language">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

3

```
<xsl:variable name="total">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="dfns:*/dfns:*[@language]" group-by="@language">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
```

4. Tried with generate-id and generate-key() function that is also not working..

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Please post a **well-formed** example of the XML input. -- Do you want to consider **all** @language attributes in the entire XML document?

Comment: @Mike: Yes. I wanted to consider all languages attributes in the xml file

Comment: Well, then my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Nodepad++ XML Tools is based on libxml wich only support XSLT 1.0.
You may try this key based solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="klanguage" match="*[@language]" use="@language"/>


  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="count( //*[
        generate-id()
        = 
        generate-id(key('klanguage', @language)[1])
      ])" />

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which generates the following output with notepad++:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>3</root>
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590316/2115381

Comment: your example works fine and as you said it's problem with XSLT version causing it. However, if i copy the same lines in my big XSLT, it doesn't give me proper result. It's not even going inside the xsl:template match="/".. Not sure what's wrong.. i am trying to figure it out. Thanks for your help though!!

Answer (score 0):

Given a well-formed input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <Date_TimeList>
      <Date_Time index="1">1404211736</Date_Time>
   </Date_TimeList>
   <Short_NameList>
      <Short_Name language="GB">ABC EUROPE</Short_Name>
   </Short_NameList>
   <Name_1List>
      <Name_1 language="GB">ABC EUROPE</Name_1>
   </Name_1List>
   <Name_2List>
      <Name_2 language="GB">ABC EUROPE</Name_2>
   </Name_2List>
   <StreetList>
      <Street language="GB">FRANKFURTER STR.107</Street>
      <Street language="FR">D-64807 DIEBURG</Street>
   </StreetList>
   <address1List>
      <address1 language="GB" index="1">Test GB Address 1</address1>
      <address1 language="FR" index="1">Test FR Address 1</address1>
      <address1 language="DE" index="1">Test DE Address 1</address1>
      <address1 language="GB" index="2">Test GB Address 2</address1>
      <address1 language="FR" index="2">Test FR Address 2</address1>
      <address1 language="GB" index="3">Test GB Address 3</address1>
   </address1List>
   <Town_CountryList>
      <Town_Country language="GB">GERMANY</Town_Country>
   </Town_CountryList>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(//@language))" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>3</result>
```

Comment: Tried your code in Notepad++ editor, getting result empty

Comment: I don't think that's an XSLT 2.0 processor, is it?

Comment: Yes Mike. XSLT 1.0 processor couldn't find function distinct-values. It throws NPE